# How to build a drag and drop hierarchical tree that automatically updates

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization

I am currently working in R and need a way to visualise a hierarchical tree...

I want to be able to initially define a tree where each node has one parent and each parent can have multiple children.

I would like the ability to drag and drop nodes under different parents and carry out some calculation (in R) that is then updated on the visualisaton e.g. let's say each node has a value; when I place a node under a parent I would like to sum the children and compare the value to the parent node.

So the question is if anyone has any ideas how to approach this or has tried anything similar?

I've been looking at shiny (e.g. shinyDND) and javascript (e.g. gojs) but rather than head off down the rabbit hole I could use some advice. The only caveat is that the updated calculations need to be done in R (they are more complicated than sums and will be recursive with analyses that I am running).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shinyTree` is a possibility. But there are some potential problems: one can drag a child in a child, or a parent in a child, or a parent in a parent. I don't know whether there is a way to prevent that (there's no built-in way, I think).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)

values_parents <- function(tree){
  sapply(tree, function(parent) attr(parent, "stinfo"))
}

total_values_children <- function(tree){
  sapply(
    lapply(tree, function(parent){
      sapply(parent, function(children){
        attr(children, "stinfo")
      })
    }),
    function(x){if(is.list(x)) NA else sum(x)}
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("pre {font-size: 17px;} .jstree-anchor {font-size: large;}"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 6,
      shinyTree("tree", dragAndDrop = TRUE, checkbox = FALSE)
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      tags$fieldset(
        tags$legend("Values of parents:"),
        verbatimTextOutput("parentsValues")
      ),
      br(),
      tags$fieldset(
        tags$legend("Total value of children:"),
        verbatimTextOutput("childrenTotalValue")
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["tree"]] <- renderTree({
    list(
      
      ParentA = structure(list(
        ChildrenA1 = structure(NA, stinfo = 5),
        ChildrenA2 = structure(NA, stinfo = 4)
      ), 
      stinfo = 10, stopened = FALSE),
      
      ParentB = structure(list(
        ChildrenB1 = structure(NA, stinfo = 6),
        ChildrenB2 = structure(NA, stinfo = 8)
      ), 
      stinfo = 12, stopened = FALSE)
      
    )
  })
  
  output[["parentsValues"]] <- renderPrint({
    values_parents(input[["tree"]])
  })
  
  output[["childrenTotalValue"]] <- renderPrint({
    total_values_children(input[["tree"]])
  })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

I *started* to do a new package: [jsTreeR](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR). As `shinyTree`, it is an R interface to the JavaScript library `jsTree`, but it allows more controls. As you can see in the example below, you cannot drag a parent and you cannot move a child inside a child:

[image]

```
library(jsTreeR)

dat <- list(
  list(
    text = "RootA",
    data = list(value = 999),
    type = "root",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "ChildA1",
        type = "child"
      ),
      list(
        text = "ChildA2",
        type = "child"
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    text = "RootB",
    type = "root",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "ChildB1",
        type = "child"
      ),
      list(
        text = "ChildB2",
        type = "child"
      )
    )
  )
)

types <- list(
  root = list(
    icon = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
  ),
  child = list(
    icon = "glyphicon glyphicon-file"
  )
)

checkCallback <- JS(
  "function(operation, node, parent, position, more) {",
  "  if(operation === 'move_node') {",
  "    if(parent.id === '#' || parent.type === 'child') {",
  "      return false;", # prevent moving a child above or below the root
  "    }",               # and moving inside a child
  "  }",
  "  return true;", # allow everything else
  "}"
)

dnd <- list(
  is_draggable = JS(
    "function(node) {",
    "  if(node[0].type !== 'child') {",
    "    return false;",
    "  }",
    "  return true;",
    "}"
  )
)

jstree(
  dat,
  dragAndDrop = TRUE, dnd = dnd,
  types = types,
  checkCallback = checkCallback
)
```

Comment: That's great thanks. Almost exactly what I was looking for. 
Do you know if there is a way to visualise it as a hierarchical tree e.g. one/two node(s) at the top, branching downwards? 

I hope I've awarded you the bounty, I've accepted your anwer.

Comment: @haffamoto Yes I've got the bounty, thanks. What do you mean by "a hierarchical tree"? A dendrogram? But anyway it's not possible to change the way the tree is displayed.

Comment: OK great, thanks for your help. Yes effectively like a dendrogram, north to south from root node(s) to leaf node(s).